# Using a variable Struct

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to write DRY Elixir, with Dave Thomas' book still in the post!

Below you see a part of a Phoenix controller that was auto-generated for a `Card`. In practise I have a variety of products that will behave exactly the same as `Card` so I want to generalise. One of my efforts is below but it does not compile with the error being at **{}**.

I'm pretty sure I'm making a fundamental mistake as I'm new to the language (but not to functional programming).

```
  alias Api.Card

  map = %{"cards" => Card, "books" => Book}

  def create(conn, %{"product" => product}) do

    # changeset = Card.changeset(%Card{}, card_params)
    changeset = map[product].changeset(%map[product]**{}**, card_params)

    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, product} ->
        conn
        |> put_status(:created)
        |> put_resp_header("location", card_path(conn, :show, card))
        # |> render("show.json", card: card)
        |> render("new_key.json", id: product.id)
```

If you can help me with this, note that I also need to turn `card_path` into a variable as well, but I think that will be along the lines of `estimate_path product`.

I also tried this, but without success as well

```
  (Struct, path) =
    case product do
        "cards" -> (Card, card_path)
        _ -> (Card, card_path)
    end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create an empty struct (with default values), you can call the auto generated `__struct__/0` function on the module.

Change

```
changeset = map[product].changeset(%map[product]**{}**, card_params)
```

to

```
changeset = map[product].changeset(map[product].__struct__, card_params)
```

To store a `card_path` function in a variable, there are atleast 2 options:

1. Store a reference to the function using `path = &card_path/3`, and then later call it as `path.(conn, :show, card)`.
2. Store it as an atom, like `path = :card_path` and use `apply/3` to call it: `apply(YourApp.Router.Helpers, path, [conn, :show, card])`.

Comment: Thanks. The first bit worked, and I'm sure you are right about the latter too. But for that, I am using Phoenix and have `resources "/estimates/:product", EstimateController, except: [:new, :edit]` so I was wondering whether there was a way of playing with `estimate_path` too?

Comment: And is this idiomatic?  I ask as now I see that I can only use `map` if it is inside `create`, whereas I need it for other functions too

Comment: You should use module attributes to store the map. Use `@map %{...}` in the module to define it, then access it using `@map` inside the functions.

Comment: Re the first question, you could create a map like `@map %{"cards" => %{module: Card, path: :card_path}, ...}`, then use the value in `:module` for `__struct__`, and `:path` with `apply`.